UIViewControllerRepresentable loses its alignment when integrated with other SwiftUI dynamic views
Targets:
Tested with

iPhone 16 Pro with iOS 18.0 (Simulator)
iPhone 6s with iOS 15.8.1 (Physical device)

I have an UIKit UIViewController component (instance of UIPageViewController, repo: here).
I'm trying to integrate this in my SwiftUI project, with the following code:
import SwiftUI
import ZTronCarouselCore

internal struct PresetsCarousel: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let navController = UINavigationController(
            rootViewController: Carousel16_9Page(
                    with: BasicMediaFactory(),
                    medias: [
                        ZTronImageDescriptor(assetName: "8.45.35"),
                        ZTronImageDescriptor(assetName: "9.35.30"),
                        ZTronImageDescriptor(assetName: "9.45.45"),
                        ZTronImageDescriptor(assetName: "11.25.35"),
                        ZTronImageDescriptor(assetName: "11.45.40"),
                        ZTronImageDescriptor(assetName: "12.25.45"),
                    ]
                )
        )
        
        navController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        
        return navController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) { } 
}

Now, when I integrate it inside a SwiftUI view, by default, a UIViewControllerRepresentable takes all the available space (by my understanding) the same way a GeometryReader does.
Though, this component is supposed to be used as a part of a SwiftUI View, there might be other components above and below, so it's natural that I try to constrain its size, for example as follows:
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    if self.orientationInfo.orientation == .portrait {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<7) { i in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(.red)
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                                    
                        Text("Lorem Ipsum")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: 100)
    }

    PresetsCarousel()
        .aspectRatio(16.0/9.0, contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                
        Text("Lorem Ipsum Dolorem Sit Amet")
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

In a way that it preserves its aspect ratio between different interface orientations, and takes only the necessary space.
Though, this produces the following effect on the physical device (simulator shows no problem):

In alternative to just
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    PresetsCarousel()
        .id("presets")
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

The latter produces the following in the simulator:

Any suggestion about how can I fix this? I have read/write access to the linked repository so I can edit the source code of the UIKit repo.
For the OrientationInfo object, please refer to this post. It is injected in the app page via .environmentObject(_:).

Can you show what your desired result looks like?

@Sweeper: The desired result is that after the device interface rotation the image doesn't disappear.
